# Pi Zero W: Second i2c Bus

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w

I did a really stupid mistake - I set up a second i²C bus months ago, so I have two gyro sensors connected - but din't document it. 
I can see the connected devices with

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

and

```
i2cdetect -y 3
```

How is it possible to activate the 2nd bus? Google won't tell me anything helpful. I think by SDA and SDC are connected to the pins BCM 5 & 6.

Comment: The Pi has only 2 I²C hardware busses (one reserved). You may be using `i2c-gpio` which is a software i2c controller. Check `config.txt` to see what you have setup.

Comment: ...and read `/boot/overlays/README` for the documentation of `i2c-gpio`.

Comment: @wernersbacher, a year ago, I read guys claiming that they could use DT overlays to setup multiple I2C buses on Rpi3B+, but no one could confirm which version of stretch they were using.  I tried a couple of times and gave up. I also read that you can use I2C bus 0, which is used by the OS, but that is risky. Now only Rpi4B officially specifies that you can use multiple I2C buses.  I tried and found it working: https://penzu.com/p/f0416d22. I placed two PCA9685 PWM modules on I2C Bus 1, and another PCA9685 in Bus 3 and use python to read write them without any problem.

Comment: @wernersbacher, The link below is the fake news I read. A couple of other forum discussions had similar instructions, some said it rubbish, some said good, but no one gave any confirmation on hardware and software raspbian version. https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/.

Comment: Thank you guys, will look into it. It definitely works, I just messed up the soldering job - so I thought about using an other PIN for bus 3.

Answer (score 5):

Setting up a software I2C bus is very simple with device tree.

For I2C bus 3 using GPIO 5 as SDA and GPIO 6 as SCL add the following entry to `/boot/config.txt` and then reboot.

```
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=5,i2c_gpio_scl=6,bus=3
```

A new I2C device with bus number 3 will then appear in `/dev`.

```
$ ls /dev/i2c*
/dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-3
$
```

You may use the same software to talk to the bus as you would use to talk to a hardware bus.

```
$ i2cdetect -y 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
$
```

Full instructions are given in `/boot/overlays/README`.

For reliability I suggest the use of external pulls to 3V3 on the GPIO used for SDA and SCL.  I would use something like 4k7 resistors (but note that the hardware bus on GPIO 2/3 uses 1k8 resistors).

Comment: +1 this worked well for configuring any pins for I2C, however, the scan took forever if I use any non-designated I2C pins. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What are non-designated I2C pins?  Are you trying to scan GPIO you haven't assigned to be a software bus?

Comment: correct! I successfully utilized pins 11 and 13 for I2C using your advice but the scan is taking forever. I assume this is because it is a software I2C controller and I do not know if there is a way to either fix that slowness or enable I2C on the hardware level somehow.

Comment: Have you added pull-ups?  They probably make a speed difference.

Comment: No I have not, I can try, will need to research how to do that right